# SecurityException occured, Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib'

Tags: c#, .net, cas, excel-dna

On this line I get the following exception:

```
using (Stream reader = File.Open(m_inputFile, FileMode.Open))
```

Exception:

```
The message is: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

This happens in an Excel addin running in ExcelDNA, however this fails as soon as the XLL for Excel is put on a network drive.

How can I allow full permissions to read from local drives as I am on a secure network ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the default security settings under .NET 2.0, which grant restricted permissions to code running over a network.

The first step is the ensure that you are running a recent version of Excel-DNA - there were some changes related to the security of the AppDomain setup a few years ago that might be relevant.

Another fix you can try is to retarget your add-in to .NET 4.0. You probably don't even have to recompile, just change your .dna file to start with:

```
<DnaLibrary RuntimeVersion="v4.0" Name="..." >
```

If you want to stick with the .NET 2.0 runtime, you can change the permissions by using the `caspol` utility. There are some detailed instructions in this post on the Google group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/exceldna/Csls-_bjDp0/G3HlxFkDefQJ

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly, I was trying to sign my dll before to read your reply ...

Comment: Did you change the target runtime version, or run caspol to change the permissions?

Comment: I changed the runtime version, I cannot make every user run capsol.exe: I understand from the Microsoft page that capsol manages rights at the machine level.